# How to bind web socket to events in .NET C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sockets, streamdeck

I am writing a plugin for the Elgato Stream Deck. The Stream Deck uses a web socket for communication with plugins. I am trying to write my plugin as a console app in C#. The ["compiled plugin" example provided by Elgato](https://github.com/elgatosf/streamdeck-cpu/tree/e5a04d3d0cc22cabe11221104909a3e0ccb6292f) is broken ([this GitHub issue points to one problem](https://github.com/elgatosf/streamdeck-cpu/issues/22), and there appear to be more) and does not appear to run - so I have been digging through the code to make sense of it and translate it to C# without using Visual Studio debugging. I did find this, however ([link to code file on GitHub](https://github.com/elgatosf/streamdeck-cpu/blob/e5a04d3d0cc22cabe11221104909a3e0ccb6292f/Sources/Common/ESDConnectionManager.cpp)):

```
void ESDConnectionManager::Run()
{
    try
    {
        // Create the endpoint
        mWebsocket.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        mWebsocket.clear_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);
    
        // Initialize ASIO
        mWebsocket.init_asio();
        
        // Register our message handler
        mWebsocket.set_open_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(&ESDConnectionManager::OnOpen, this, &mWebsocket, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1));
        mWebsocket.set_fail_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(&ESDConnectionManager::OnFail, this, &mWebsocket, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1));
        mWebsocket.set_close_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(&ESDConnectionManager::OnClose, this, &mWebsocket, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1));
        mWebsocket.set_message_handler(websocketpp::lib::bind(&ESDConnectionManager::OnMessage, this, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2));
    
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
        std::string uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:" + std::to_string(mPort);
        WebsocketClient::connection_ptr connection = mWebsocket.get_connection(uri, ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            DebugPrint("Connect initialization error: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
            return;
        }
    
        mConnectionHandle = connection->get_handle();
    
        // Note that connect here only requests a connection. No network messages are
        // exchanged until the event loop starts running in the next line.
        mWebsocket.connect(connection);
    
        // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
        // this will cause a single connection to be made to the server. mWebsocket.run()
        // will exit when this connection is closed.
        mWebsocket.run();
    }
    catch (websocketpp::exception const & e)
    {
        // Prevent an unused variable warning in release builds
        (void)e;
        DebugPrint("Websocket threw an exception: %s\n", e.what());
    }
}
```

This appears to be using some [library called boost.asio](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264257/Socket-Programming-in-Cplusplus-using-boost-asio-T)? The closest thing I can find in C# is the `MessageWebSocket` from `Windows.Networking.Sockets` ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocket?view=winrt-22621)) but this appears to be only for Windows RT?

How do I create something analogous to this in a .NET console app? I have found references to `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0)), which appears to be the class I need, but I am not sure.

I have found a few samples ([such as this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-7.0), [and this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh202858(v=vs.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - both of which use yet another socket class, `Socket`) that show how to use Sockets in general, but they do not seem event-driven. They seem to send, and then immediately receive data. I want a web socket that calls local methods (akin to event handlers) when events/data are received by the socket. I believe this is what is going on in the sample C++ code above (specifically Open, Fail, Close, and Message). My understanding is that I need to do some work (["register" with the Stream Deck](https://developer.elgato.com/documentation/stream-deck/sdk/registration-procedure/)) on the web socket "Open" event, and then handle the web socket "Message" event and parse out what event the Stream Deck is reporting happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down some lines in your example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-7.0 you will find a example called: [Asyncronous Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-7.0#asynchronous-mode) that handles sending and receiving separately.

Send part

```cs
   int bytesSent = 0;
    while (bytesSent < requestBytes.Length)
    {
        bytesSent += await socket.SendAsync(requestBytes.AsMemory(bytesSent), SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

If you do not want the program to lock up, the easiest way would be to start a thread for listening maybe?